# Javascript chart fills up the entire browser window

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

I'm creating my first chart using chart.js.

The chart is displayed like I want it to except for the fact that it always fills up the entire browser screen.

I have tried setting the chart dimensions to 100 but it doesn't seem to work.

I have created a jsFiddle that showcases my issue:

https://jsfiddle.net/1q5oej4q/

Also, here's the code if you wanna view it here:

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    displayLineChart();

    function displayLineChart() {
        var data = {
            labels: ['first', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Prime and Fibonacci",
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
            }, {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
            }]
        };

        var chart = document.getElementById("lineChart");
        chart.width = 100;
        chart.height = 100;

        var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
        ctx.canvas.width = 100;
        ctx.canvas.height = 100;
        var options = {};
        var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: data,
        });
    }
});
```

Html:

```
<canvas id="lineChart">
</canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a `<div>`, then size that:

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <canvas id="lineChart">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1q5oej4q/1/).

Comment: All good! :) Just for further explanation, the chart's size is relative to its parent element, that's why this works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fill the `options` and pass it as a parameter to the Chart.

```
$(function() {
    displayLineChart();

    function displayLineChart() {
        var data = {
            labels: ['first', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Prime and Fibonacci",
                fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
            }, {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data: [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
            }]
        };

        var chart = document.getElementById("lineChart");
        chart.width = 500;
        chart.height = 500;

        var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart").getContext("2d");
        ctx.canvas.width = 500;
        ctx.canvas.height = 500;
        var options = {
            responsive: false,
            maintainAspectRatio: true
        };
        var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: data,
            options: options
        });
    }
});
```